# Translate Animation - End Position

Tags: java, android

I need to animate my view with translate animation to a X (150) and Y (100) position in one second. It's working well with this code:

```
Animation translate = new 
TranslateAnimation(0, 150 - view.getLeft(), 0, 100 - view.getTop());
translate.setDuration(1000);
view.setAnimation(translate);
translate.start();
```

But I need the view keeps at this position (150, 100) when the animation finishes, then I called the *setAnimationListener* and did this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (animation == translate) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        params.topMargin = 100;
        params.leftMargin = 150;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

The problem is that at the end of the animation, the view flashes once (very fast, almost imperceptible) and then the view moves to another position, very near the desired position (150, 100), but not exactly.

If I set *translate.setFillAfter(true)* it works. But, if I need to apply another animation to the same view, will it work as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this :

```
fillAfter=true
fillEnabled=true
```